# PyQt5 move QDockWidget by dragging tab

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

The clip below shows dragging `QDockWidget`s between docking areas by dragging the tabs (not the title bar) - but when I try this with PyQt 5.15.0 it doesn't work, the tabs won't detach. How can I enable this behavior?

What I want:
https://www.screencast.com/t/lv83SoyVUhbd (from https://woboq.com/blog/qdockwidget-changes-in-56.html)

What I get:
https://www.screencast.com/t/bIUj4vLNTF

My code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    dock1 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Blue")
    dock2 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Green")
    dock3 = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Red")

    content1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content1.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;")

    content2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content2.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")

    content3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content3.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")

    dock1.setWidget(content1)
    dock2.setWidget(content2)
    dock3.setWidget(content3)

    dock1.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock2.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock3.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)

    main.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock1)
    main.tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
    main.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock3)

    main.resize(400, 200)
    main.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to my question was enabling the `GroupedDragging` with `setDockOptions` on the `QMainWindow`. I managed to get a really nice appearance & behavior exactly like I wanted with the code below.

Demo: https://www.screencast.com/t/GU5Z2ysT

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class DockWidget(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__(title)
        self.setTitleBarWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
        self.dockLocationChanged.connect(self.on_dockLocationChanged)

    def on_dockLocationChanged(self):
        main: QtWidgets.QMainWindow = self.parent()
        all_dock_widgets = main.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget)

        for dock_widget in all_dock_widgets:
            sibling_tabs = main.tabifiedDockWidgets(dock_widget)
            # If you pull a tab out of a group the other tabs still see it as a sibling while dragging...
            sibling_tabs = [s for s in sibling_tabs if not s.isFloating()]

            if len(sibling_tabs) != 0:
                # Hide title bar
                dock_widget.setTitleBarWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
            else:
                # Re-enable title bar
                dock_widget.setTitleBarWidget(None)

    def minimumSizeHint(self) -> QtCore.QSize:
        return QtCore.QSize(100, 100)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    dock1 = DockWidget("Blue")
    dock2 = DockWidget("Green")
    dock3 = DockWidget("Red")

    content1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content1.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;")
    content1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    content2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content2.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")
    content2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    content3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content3.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")
    content3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    dock1.setWidget(content1)
    dock2.setWidget(content2)
    dock3.setWidget(content3)

    dock1.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock2.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock3.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)

    main.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock1)
    main.tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
    main.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock3)

    main.setDockOptions(main.GroupedDragging | main.AllowTabbedDocks | main.AllowNestedDocks)

    main.setTabPosition(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas, QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
    main.resize(400, 200)
    main.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: It does not work properly. When you try to close the application through the close button, the application does not close. The approach is really nice, but it breaks the termination of the application. I am facing the same issue, and sometimes, this causes some docks to remain visible.

Comment: If you print out who is receiving the locationChanged signal, only one of them is. This means that even if you drag a dock, it will not update the location. Not only this, by a certain combination you get a crash: sibling_tabs = main.tabifiedDockWidgets(dock_widget)
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget' object has no attribute 'tabifiedDockWidgets'

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a little extra to the accepted answer.
This version works with Qt5 and Qt6 and is able to detect corner cases like pulling out a tab and dropping it in the same group or merging a floating tab group with a docked window:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

from typing import TypeVar, List, Optional

TDockWidget = TypeVar('TDockWidget', bound='DockWidget')


class DockWidget(QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self: TDockWidget, title: str, parent: Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None) -> None:
        super(_DockWidget, self).__init__(title, parent)
        self.setTitleBarWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget())
        self.visibilityChanged.connect(self.on_visibility_changed)
        self.dockLocationChanged.connect(self.on_dock_location_changed)

    @QtCore.Slot(bool)
    def on_visibility_changed(self: TDockWidget, is_visible: bool) -> None:
        # this visibility monitor is really only needed to detect merges of
        # tabbed, floating windows with existing docked windows
        if not is_visible and isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
            main_window: QtWidgets.QMainWindow = self.parent()
            all_dockwidgets: List[QtWidgets.QDockWidget] = main_window.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget)
            for dockwidget in all_dockwidgets:
                if hasattr(dockwidget, 'on_dock_location_changed'):
                    dockwidget.on_dock_location_changed(main_window.dockWidgetArea(dockwidget), False)

    @QtCore.Slot(Qt.DockWidgetArea)
    def on_dock_location_changed(self: TDockWidget, area: Qt.DockWidgetArea, update_others: bool = True) -> None:
        if not isinstance(self.parent(), QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
            # mysterious parents call for a title
            self.setTitleBarWidget(None)
            return

        main_window: QtWidgets.QMainWindow = self.parent()
        if not main_window.tabifiedDockWidgets(self):
            # if there's no siblings we ain't a tab!
            self.setTitleBarWidget(None)

            if not update_others:
                # prevent infinite recursion
                return

            # force an update to all other docks that may now no longer be tabs
            all_dockwidgets: List[QtWidgets.QDockWidget] = main_window.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDockWidget)
            for dockwidget in all_dockwidgets:
                if dockwidget != self and hasattr(dockwidget, 'on_dock_location_changed'):
                    dockwidget.on_dock_location_changed(main_window.dockWidgetArea(dockwidget), False)
            return

        # at this point the dockwidget is either a resting tab or a tab
        # that is being dragged and hasn't been dropped yet (siblings are updated post-drop)
        # collect all siblings of this dockwidget...
        tab_siblings: List[QtWidgets.QDockWidget] = main_window.tabifiedDockWidgets(self)
        # and filter for non-floating siblings in the same area
        tab_siblings = [x for x in tab_siblings if main_window.dockWidgetArea(x) == area and not x.isFloating()]

        if tab_siblings:
            if self.titleBarWidget() is not None:
                # no changes needed, prevent infinite recursion
                return

            # show a title if we're not floating (this tab is settled),
            # hide it otherwise (this tab just became floating but wasn't dropped)
            self.setTitleBarWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget() if not self.isFloating() else None)

            # in this case it's also a good idea to tell to reconsider their situation
            # since Qt won't notify them separately
            for sibling in tab_siblings:
                if hasattr(sibling, 'on_dock_location_changed'):
                    sibling.on_dock_location_changed(main_window.dockWidgetArea(sibling), True)
        else:
            self.setTitleBarWidget(None)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()

    dock1 = DockWidget("Blue")
    dock2 = DockWidget("Green")
    dock3 = DockWidget("Red")

    content1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content1.setStyleSheet("background-color:blue;")
    content1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    content2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content2.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;")
    content2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    content3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    content3.setStyleSheet("background-color:red;")
    content3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

    dock1.setWidget(content1)
    dock2.setWidget(content2)
    dock3.setWidget(content3)

    dock1.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock2.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)
    dock3.setAllowedAreas(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas)

    main.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, dock1)
    main.tabifyDockWidget(dock1, dock2)
    main.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock3)

    main.setDockOptions(main.GroupedDragging | main.AllowTabbedDocks | main.AllowNestedDocks)

    main.setTabPosition(Qt.AllDockWidgetAreas, QtWidgets.QTabWidget.North)
    main.resize(400, 200)
    main.show()

    app.exec_()
```